# exchange 2007 2010 ews code migration

Tags: exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Our intranet (apache/php) is currently talking to our Exchange 2003 server via webdav. Our company was looking at upgrading from Exchange 2007 a while back, we even had the test server up and running and there was some effort made to port our webdav functionality to use the new EWS.  The project was shelved for a while, but we are now looking at upgrading to 2010. Are there any big differences between the two EWSs? (I haven't been able to track down any articles about 2007 2010 EWS *code* migration.)

Comment: Is this via the Managed API? If so it should just be a case of changing the Exchange2007 constant to a 2010 constant. That this exists shows there is definately a difference - though I couldn't say how much.

Comment: Our code is basically a bunch of http requests and xml parsing/generation done with PHP. I'm hoping someone will tell me the soap requests/responses look exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to close this up. No modifications to EWS code were needed when migrating between servers.